# How to mock a function whose parent object is of nullable type?

Tags: angular, jestjs, karma-jasmine, angular-spectator

This is my method.

```
redirect(){
   const url = 'localhost:4100';
   this.document.defaultView?.open(url, '_blank'); 
}
```

Obviously open() is present in defaultView. However, when I try to mock it, I'm getting an error `open` is not part of this object.

```
const spyOpen = spyOn(document.defaultView, 'open').and.callFake(
  (url: string, target: string = '_blank'): void => {
    url;
    target;
  }
);
```

Comment: So is it Jest or Jasmine? It's either one or another.

Comment: I will prefer jest. But if I can solve this problem even in Jasmine, that will be something already.

Answer (score 1):

In Jest, it can be:

```
jest.spyOn(document.defaultView as Required<typeof document.defaultView>, 'open')
```

The problem is that if `document.defaultView.open` is really not a function at runtime, Jest will fail to spy on it, in this case it cannot make use of spies maintained by Jest and needs to be cleaned up manually:

```
originalOpen = document.defaultView.open;
document.defaultView.open = jest.fn();

// in afterEach
document.defaultView.open = originalOpen;
```

The same can be applied to Jasmine, adjusted for difference in API.

Comment: do you mean it should be `document.defaultView?.open = jest.fn();` defaultView is actually nullable.

Comment: It's `document.defaultView!.open` then. And it will fail at runtime if defaultView isn't an object.

Comment: using an exclamation point, I am getting this error `Forbidden non-null assertion.`

Comment: It's worth mentioning where the error comes from. It's linter, isn't it? Silence it then because this is the correct thing to do in this case.

Comment: We're not allowed to silence the linter. I had to split the tests in 2 describe.

Comment: Linter rules are supposed to improve the code, this one hurts it. To make it clear, this needs to be done with eslint-disable-next-line, it has to be allowed per need basis in any company regardless of the policy. A workaround for this rule is to use a type guard, `if (document.defaultView) ... `, also assert that document.defaultView is truthy to not skip a part of the test based on wrong assumptions on its availability. No need to do structural changes to tests